# Comment warning appears on next comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

I see a comment warning reappear after I fix the problem, submit the comment, and start a new comment.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Write a comment that will produce a warning (I used notifying two users as seen below in the first screenshot, but any warning will work [See Nathan's elaboration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297245/4320665)).  Try to submit it.
2. Fix the comment so that it submits.  Submit it without dismissing the warning manually.  The warning will be hidden when you submit the comment.
3. Add a new comment.  The warning should reappear (second screenshot)

[image: First valid error]

I know I did not dismiss the warning, but it seemed to go away after my comment was submitted.  It then reappeared when adding a new comment.

[image: Error reappeared]

Comment: adding first comment so people can test this here rather than somewhere else

Comment: @Tanner - Testing this out.

Comment: Yep, got the warning back up this time.

Comment: In fact, it will stay for the *next* comment as well if you don't dismiss it.

Comment: So, a warning stays if you don't dismiss it? Next there'll be a bug that a dialog stays up if you don't click OK or Cancel :P Just kidding, if it goes away the first time, it should stay away, irrespective of active dismissal.

Comment: Dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258622/293416

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed as of build 3740 for MSE/MSO, and build 2863 on other sites.

Thanks again to Ilmari Karonen for getting to the heart of the issue. The fix I implemented doesn't use the `comment` event; having direct access to the code that triggers that event, there was an easier way to just make *that* dismiss the message box rather than having to add an event handler. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

I just had this happen for the minimum comment length error as well.  My comment was too short when I clicked add comment.  I added to my comment without clearing the flag and pressed add comment.  It took my comment and the next time I went to add a comment the error showed up.  I then tried with a blacklisted link like

> let me google that for you: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=test

I got the error that the comment can't contain that content.  Without clearing it I removed the link and was able to post the comment.  I added another comment and the error was still there.  I am guessing that all errors that aren't cleared will resurface on the next comment.

Answer (score 5):

It indeed looks like someone forgot to remove the message boxes when a comment is successfully submitted.  Here's a simple JS three-liner to fix it:

```js
$( document ).on( 'comment', function ( event, postid ) {
    $( '#add-comment-' + postid + ' .message-dismissable' ).fadeOutAndRemove();
} );
```

(I didn't even have to use any ugly hacks to detect successful comment submissions, since the SE framework fires a convenient custom event for them.  Thanks, whoever added that little feature!)

I've added this fix to the development branch of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), and it should be part of the next stable release (v1.32) shortly.

Comment: Hey I just tested it and this works.  Looking forward to the next release and a [meta-tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: It's not really [meta-tag:status-completed] until someone actually adds that fix to the SE codebase, though. SOUP is just a klugy work-around.

Comment: Ah.  Well hopefully SE will use this fix.  I wonder if the accept is better or worse for having them put in the fix.